# Running WMIC file version over network?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to run WMIC over the network to get the version of a specific file. I know to get a local file version you can do:

```
wmic datafile where name='\\C:\localfile.exe' get version
```

What if I want to find it over the network? like this:

```
wmic datafile where name='\\fileserver\\e$\\file.exe' get version
```

is it possible to do this? I do have a username and password to the servers in question.

Answer (score 1):

```
wmic /NODE fileserver /USER user /PASSWORD pass datafile where name='e:\\file.exe' get version
```

Yes, you need to indicate user and password unless the user doing the query has rights on the remote node.

You query is executed against a local (to the remote machine) database that have the elements registered with local (to the remote) paths.

And backslashes need to be escaped